Ambient light and total internal reflection
I'm a retired high school physics teacher writing a story about underwater dwellers. The standard explanation of total internal reflection (TIR) doesn't seem to address some questions that have arisen in my writing.

Videos show TIR as seen by an underwater observer during daylight. Since the water surrounding the observer is itself illuminated, I assume that this light is due to sunlight transmitted through the water, and that this is the light reflected back into the water from the observer's line of sight. Is my assumption correct? (This would also apply in the case where an underwater civilization generated its own light.)

Absent artificial underwater lighting, would TIR still be observed at night?   Particularly when the moon isn't visible? I think not, but I'm no expert in optics.

Finally, could underwater observers see stars when they look upward in dark water at night?



How far underwater do these dwellers live? Also, you might be interested in [worldbuilding.se], which is devoted to scientific and pseudo-scientific explanations for sci-fi/fantasy writing.

You can observe all of the phenomenology of total internal reflection in your local swimming pool, if you want. Ideally you should have the pool to yourself to get as little wave action as possible. Absent that, nothing stops you from getting an underwater case for your cell phone and from performing experiments in your bathtub using its camera.

Propagation in both water and air is reciprocal. So if you can see down to one place (1) in water from another place (2) above in air, then you can also see that place (2) by looking up while in (1). In practice, TIR restricts the field of view in the higher index material looking in to the lower index one.
